# How can I drive my Greek registered car in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom

I just moved to the UK with the intent to work but with a short term contract of 12 months (internship position). I realized that the working place is in a very isolated area without public means. The car has a regular registration on my name (greek citizenship). I read similar questions-answers. However I was wondering if a certain exception can be applied since the job position is an internship and an annual contract, meaning that most probably after the end of the 12 months I will be leaving the country again. It is also probable that I do not complete the year either in case other problems arise. Can I at least use it for the 6 month period?
Thank you

Comment: As I understand it, you can use it for a year. (I assume the car is registered/insured to an address in Greece, otherwise there may be issues with the insurance).

Comment: [Apparently](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/registration/registration-abroad//united-kingdom/index_en.htm) the rules say six months.